# Wire:click not firing event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have written this code here `like.blade.php`

```
<span class="inline-flex items-center text-sm">

  <button wire:click="like" class="inline-flex space-x-2 {{ $post->isLiked() ? 'text-green-400 hover:text-green-500' : 'text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500' }} focus:outline-none focus:ring-0">
    <svg class="h-5 w-5" x-description="solid/thumb-up" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
        <pat d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z"></pat>
    </svg>

    <span class="font-medium text-gray-900">{{ $count }}</span>
    <span class="sr-only">likes</span>
  </button>
</span>
```

And the component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;

class Like extends Component
{
    public Post $post;
    public $count;

    public function mount(Post $post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->count = $post->likes_count;
    }

    public function like()
    {
            dd('fixed');
        if ($this->post->isLiked()) {
            $this->post->removeLike();

            $this->count--;
        } elseif (auth()->user()) {
            $this->post->likes()->create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            ]);

            $this->count++;
        } elseif (($ip = request()->ip()) && ($userAgent = request()->userAgent())) {
            $this->post->likes()->create([
                'ip' => $ip,
                'user_agent' => $userAgent,
            ]);

            $this->count++;
        }
    }

    public function ohyee(){

        dd('heree');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.like');
    }
}
```

The problem is wire:click is not firing the function like what is the problem why livewire is not firing the event , what am i missing ?

p.s I have used wire:click in other blades and they are working fine..

Comment: did you wrap all the blade code into a root div container? Also, confirm if the livewire assets are loaded

Comment: Yes i did both of them